# How to make text after "read -p" bold?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, text

I want to echo a text before the read with `read -p`.

How can I make the text inside of the `read -p` bold? I don't want the user input to be bold. I just want the "content" part bold.

Example: `read -p "content:"`. `content:` should be bold.

I tried `tput bold`/`tput sgr0` and `\e[1m`.

Comment: What type of terminal window are you using? Is it gnome-terminal, xterm, Windows cmd, Mac Terminal?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $TERM`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Im using Xterm. The output of echo $TERM is Xterm.

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
read -p "${bold}content:${normal}" input
```

Comment: @Christi123321 It would help if you shared the error you got.

Comment: @Christi123321: This works with Unbuntu for me: `echo -en "\x1b\x5b\x31\x6dcontent:\x1b\x28\x42\x1b\x5b\x6d"; read input` Escape sequences have the disadvantage that they do not work with every OS the same way.